# How to insert quotation mark in a string containg variables in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, hyperlink, escaping

I want to generate a string like the one mentioned below in C# code behind:

```
<a href="~/Online Exam/Question.aspx?id=1"></a>
```

The code which I am using right now is shown below:

```
string url= string.Format("\"~/Online Exam/Question.aspx?id={0}\"", id);
td.Text = "<a href=" + url + ">" + id + "</a>";
```

but I am not able to get the desired output with the above code. please help me out with this.

Comment: What do you get? The code looks OK.

Comment: Allthough `">" + id + "</a>"` doesn't match the sample.

Comment: What is wrong with the output?  Right now I am assuming that the td variable is an element on your webpage, so I believe you should use innerhtml and not text.

Comment: td is TableCell which i have generated dynamically. What I want is to get a 'id' displayed in 'td.text' as a link which will be directed to 'url' and will contain the 'id' as query string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
string url= String.Format("~/Online Exam/Question.aspx?id={0}", id);
td.Text = String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", url, id);
```

or if you care about `String.Format()` performance (because of culture-specificity):

```
string url= String.Concat("~/Online Exam/Question.aspx?id=", id);
td.Text = String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", url, id);
```

---

Right! Because `<a>` doesn't parse `~` as application root, only `<asp:HyperLink>` does. So

```
td.Controls.Add(new HyperLink { Text = id, NavigateUrl= url });
```

Comment: tried out the code but the output which gets stored in td.text is http://localhost:51231/OnlineExam/Online%20Exam/~/Online

Comment: @Piyush: is `td` a server-side control? is it `<asp:TableCell>`?

Comment: yes it is a server-side control, I have generated it from code behind

Comment: +1 for the best solution possible which is adding Server Control (Hyperlink) instead of assigning the raw HTML of the table cell. This way .NET framework itself will handle all the quotes mess. :)

Comment: @shadow but it isn't giving away the desired output, everything seems to be just fine but dunno why it isn't working.

Comment: @Piyush - Explain what you mean by "it isn't working" and we'll try to help. You get error? You see blank cell? You see cat in there? Add comment with details please.

Comment: @Piyush: Please edit your original question to add: cell generation code; resulting output html

Comment: @shadow @Abatishchev I am extremely sorry guys, it was a silly mistake which I was doing. Your answer was perfect. Thanks a tonne for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the quotation mark in the last line, like:

```
string url= string.Format("~/Online Exam/Question.aspx?id={0}", id);
td.Text = "<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + id + "</a>";
```

Makes the code more logical as well, since your variable `url` is now really containing only the url.

(not tested)

Comment: It's better to use `String.Format` in both cases, or `String.Concat()` in first and `String.Format()` in seconds.